# ASP.Net WebForm: How IsPostBack property gets true when form submit

Tags: webforms

### see this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

i just like to know who and how IsPostBack property gets true when form submit just clicking on submit button. who set the IsPostBack property to true ?

please share the info if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a property controlled by the ASP.NET framework in the System.Web dll - specifically in the System.Web.UI.Page class.

```csharp
/// <summary>Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.</summary>
/// <returns>true if the page is being loaded in response to a client postback; otherwise, false.</returns>
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public bool IsPostBack
{
    get
    {
        if (this._requestValueCollection == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this._isCrossPagePostBack)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (this._pageFlags[8])
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.ViewStateMacValidationErrorWasSuppressed)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.Context.ServerExecuteDepth > 0 && (this.Context.Handler == null || base.GetType() != this.Context.Handler.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return !this._fPageLayoutChanged;
    }
}
```